How to send requests to the azure bot service using private endpoint when using node.js botbuilder library?
I am using "botbuilder" library to connect to my azure bot. My azure bot has an active Teams channel. I want to disable public access to my bot service so I created a private endpoint and disabled public access for the azure bot. How do I need to change the BotFrameworkAdapter configuration in my node.js application for my application to use the private endpoint FQDN instead of bot service public url.
private createAdapter = () => {
    this.adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter(this.getConfiguration());
    this.adapter.onTurnError = this.onTurnErrorHandler;
    this.adapter.use(...this.middleware.loadBeforeRequestHandlers());
};

private getConfiguration = (): BotFrameworkAdapterSettings => {
    const MicrosoftAppId = this.config.get('MICROSOFT_BOT_APP_ID');
    const MicrosoftAppPassword = this.config.get('MICROSOFT_BOT_APP_SECRET');
    return {
        appId: MicrosoftAppId,
        appPassword: MicrosoftAppPassword,
    };
};


Please refer the below Sample - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/7762f98e78a2bec214e826a871dac0fc0e31cf87/samples/app-sso/nodejs/infra/azure.bicep#L27
